# Starting win service from command line using its path

Tags: command-line, windows-services

I'm working on script to automate installing and starting windows service.
I want to start this service from command line but its name may change, so i want to start it using its path ... is that applicable
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a service defined in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services`  as `MyService` and has attribute (String value) `binPath=c:\myprogram1.exe` , then you can change it's start-up options using the `SC` command like this:

```
SC CONFIG MyService binPath=c:\myprogram2.exe obj=".\LocalSystem" password=""
```

Then use `net start MyService` to start your service.

Here ( http://ss64.com/nt/sc.html ) you can find more available options.

Comment: I want replacement for this line in the script "sc start MyService" with something like that  "sc start MyServicePath"

Comment: you can execute first the command above, and then the `net start MyService` to start the service

Comment: SC CONFIG MyService binPath=c:\myprogram2.exe obj=".\LocalSystem" password=""... in my script i have no name for the service only i know its path so i cannot use this line